# Got late initialisation error in `_imageFile` ..... can you help me?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem with this code, late keyword showed null safety error.

```
Widget imageProfile() {
    return Center(
      child: Stack(children:[
        CircleAvatar(
          radius: 80.0,
          backgroundImage: _imageFile!=null? AssetImage("images/fcd.png"):FileImage(File(_imageFile.path)) as ImageProvider,
        ),
        Positioned(
          bottom: 20.0,
          right: 20.0,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              showModalBottomSheet(
                context: context,
                builder: ((builder) => bottomSheet()),
              );
            },
            child: Icon(
              Icons.camera_alt,
              color: Color.fromRGBO(2, 0, 46, 1),
              size: 28.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
```

Comment: you used `late` in _imageUrl, so must be initialize with value, Otherwise remove the late keyword

Comment: When I delete the word late, an error appears... What do you think is the solution?

Comment: please share your code instead of image

Comment: I edited my question and added the code

Answer (score 0):

Your `_imageUrl` is set as `late`, so it must be initialized before being used or it throws an exception. You could set a [CircularProgressIndicator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CircularProgressIndicator-class.html) while the data that `_imageUrl` should receive is being fetched and when it's complete then the screen would be built. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67258178/16030126) has an example of CircularProgressIndicator being used for it.

I recommend putting your code in the question itself, so it's easier to people visualize it and help you with the problem :)

Comment: Could you write me the code, please? I am a beginner in this language

Comment: I just set it up